# hog_haar_person_detection problem

Tags: openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I want to execute this package> [hog_haar_person_detection](https://github.com/angusleigh/hog_haar_person_detection)

But I don’t know how to complete this instruction from the author:

> Launch your camera node and have it
> publish to the "image_topic" parameter
> specified in
> hog_haar_person_detection.launch

Im working with a Kinect and Openni, so Im only executing this command:

> roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

but when run the program It doesn’t publish any window

(thanks Akif)

this is the  topic list (rostopic list) after running openni.launch

```
espe@espe-desktop:~$ rostopic list
/camera/depth/disparity
/camera/depth/image
/camera/depth/image/compressed
/camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image/compressedDepth
/camera/depth/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image/theora
/camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_rect
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressed
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_rect/theora
/camera/depth/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/points
/camera/depth_registered/disparity
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressed
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/theora
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressed
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressedDepth
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image/theora
/camera/depth_registered/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressed
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressedDepth
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/theora
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_rect_ir/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/rectify_ir/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rectify_ir/parameter_updates
/camera/rectify_mono/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rectify_mono/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono/theora
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_rect_mono/theora/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223744/hog_haar_person_detection-problem/) by [G212](https://answers.ros.org/users/25216/g212/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In  `hog_haar_person_detection.launch`, "`image_topic`" parameter is defined as "`/openni/rgb/image_raw`". Therefore openni should publish raw images to this topic, or you should set this parameter accordingly. I can help further if you can post your topic list (`rostopic list`) after running openni.launch.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [G212](https://answers.ros.org/users/25216/g212/) on 2016-01-10**:
thanks!!! right away! I change the launch file to this topic /camera/rgb/image_rect_mono, and it is working!! thanks ... but is not detecting as good as openni_tracker, did you know another package for tracking persons???

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-11**:
AFAIK, haar face detectors require clean front view of face and HOG person detector works best with upright normal views. Therefore this package may not be enough for high performance tracking. BTW, please mark the answer as accepted so other users can use this answer for a similar problem.